# unable to hide a div which have specific attribute

Tags: css

i have the following Div:-

```
<div data-automation-id="pageHeader" class="bc_bi_ada2ac09 rn_bi_ada2ac09">
```

and i am trying to hide it using this css, but the div is not been hide:-

```
[data-automation-id]="pageHeader"
{
display:none;

}
```

any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector syntax is a bit off. It should be `element[attribute="value"]` to style a element from it's custom attribute. [Attribute Selectors - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```css
div[data-automation-id="pageHeader"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div data-automation-id="pageHeader" class="bc_bi_ada2ac09 rn_bi_ada2ac09">Text</div>
```

If the HTML element won't always be a `<div>`, you can also use this selector syntax `[attr=value]` which represents elements with an attribute name of `attr` whose value is exactly `value`.

```css
[data-automation-id=pageHeader] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div data-automation-id="pageHeader" class="bc_bi_ada2ac09 rn_bi_ada2ac09">Text</div>
```